# Квадраты рисуются в неправильном месте. LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

Квадраты рисуются в неправильном месте.
Я хочу чтобы квадрат появился в верхнем левом углу.

```
map = new int[][]{{1, 0,0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

[image: Экран]

Mygame.java:

```
package com.kucer0043.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;
import java.util.Date;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;


public class MyGame extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {

    int screen_x;
    int screen_y;
    int map_x;
    int map_y;
    int rect_x_end;
    int rect_y_end;

    int[][] map;
    @Override
    public void create () {
        map_x = 4;
        map_y = 4;
        map = new int[][]{{1, 0,0, 0},
                            {0, 0, 0, 0},
                            {0, 0, 0, 0},
                            {0, 0, 0, 0}};
        System.out.println(map[0][0]);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        screen_x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        screen_y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        rect_x_end = screen_x / map_x;
        rect_y_end = screen_y / map_y;
        ScreenUtils.clear(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f, 0);

        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(0f,0f,0f,0f);
        for (int i=0;i<map_x;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<map_y;j++){
                if (map[i][j] == 1) {
                    System.out.println("i= " + i + " i*rect_x_end " + i * rect_x_end);
                    System.out.println("j= " + j + " j*rect_y_end " + j * rect_y_end);
                    shapeRenderer.rect(i * rect_x_end, j * rect_y_end,rect_x_end, rect_y_end);
                }  //System.out.println(i*rect_x_end);

            }
        }
        //batch_white.draw(img, x, y);

        //batch_black.draw(img, x, y);
        shapeRenderer.end();
        shapeRenderer.dispose();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispose () {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if(keycode== Input.Keys.LEFT) {}
        if(keycode== Input.Keys.RIGHT) {}


        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2(screenX, screenY);

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(float amountX, float amountY) {
        return false;
    }

    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    private Rectangle rectangle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данной библиотеке вертикальная ось `0y` [направлена **вверх**](https://libgdx.com/wiki/start/a-simple-game):

> By default, all rendering in libGDX (and OpenGL) is performed with the ***y-axis pointing upwards***. The x/y coordinates of the bucket define the bottom left corner of the bucket

Следовательно, для установки первого прямоугольника в *верхний левый* угол придётся либо изменить карту:

```java
map_x = 4;
map_y = 4;
map = new int[map_y][map_x] {
    {0, 0, 0, 0}, // [0][0] - левый нижний, [0][3] - правый нижний
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, 0, 0, 0}  // [3][0] - левый верхний, [3][3] - правый верхний
};
```

либо соответственно пересчитывать координаты (для первоначальной карты):

```java
for (int i = 0; i < map_x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < map_y; j++) {
        if (map[i][j] == 1) {
            int start_y = screen_y - (j + 1) * rect_y_end;
            System.out.println("i= " + i + " i*rect_x_end " + i * rect_x_end);
            System.out.println("j= " + j + " j*rect_y_end " + start_y);
            shapeRenderer.rect(i * rect_x_end, start_y, rect_x_end, rect_y_end);
        }  //System.out.println(i*rect_x_end);
    }
}
```

Для `map[0][0]`: `start_y = screen_y - rect_y_end`

---

Также можно попытаться изменить направление оси, см. [основной Stackoverflow: Changing the Coordinate System in LibGDX (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708379/changing-the-coordinate-system-in-libgdx-java)

Comment: Спасибо мне это помогло.